# When saving many uploaded files to db save() method only really works for the last file in the query

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I am using CreateView and in the template, I am uploading multiple files to store in the database. I get all file from the request by `files = self.request.FILES.getlist('file')` and loop it to create an object for each one. However, object creation only works for the last object in the list.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    files = self.request.FILES.getlist('file')
    allowed_file_extensions = ['xls', 'xlsx', 'doc', 'docx', 'pdf']
    for file in files:
        file_converted_to_string = str(file)
        file_regex = re.search(r"([a-zA-Z0-9-_\s]+)[.](\w+?)$", file_converted_to_string)
        file_name, file_extension = file_regex.group(1), file_regex.group(2)
        if file_extension in allowed_file_extensions:
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            self.object.file = file
            self.object.file_name = file_name
            self.object.file_extension = file_extension
            self.object.department_belonged = self.request.user.profile.department
            print(self.request.user.profile.department)
            self.object.creator = self.request.user
            self.object.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Even more interesting, when I replace:

```
self.object = form.save(commit=False)
self.object.file = file
self.object.file_name = file_name
self.object.file_extension = file_extension
self.object.department_belonged = self.request.user.profile.department
self.object.creator = self.request.user
self.object.save()
```

with:

```
self.model.objects.create(file=file,
                          file_name=file_name,
                          file_extension=file_extension,
                          department_belonged=self.request.user.profile.department,
                          creator=self.request.user)
```

It create a new object for each file in the list but raise error in upload_to function in models.py.

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to=file_path)

def file_path(instance, filename):
    return f'{instance.creator.profile.department}/user_{instance.creator.id}/{filename}'
```

**Error:**

> Exception Value:  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'profile'

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you keep on using `self.object` for each of the file objects. This will keep overwriting the same object on each save. So on each save you are updating the existing database row.

For the approach with `self.model.objects.create(file=file,....`  there is no `creator` associated with the instance before it is saved and as this method by-passes using an object (from memory) it wont work. I would recommend trying:

```
obj = self.model(
    file=file,
    file_name=file_name,
    file_extension=file_extension,
    department_belonged=self.request.user.profile.department,
    creator=self.request.user
)
obj.save()
```

This was the object will be created and allow reference before `file_path` is called.

Comment: This did not solve the issue. It successfully saves the instance but throws the same error on the userside.